# Clearing the screen using assembly language

Tags: assembly

I am trying to build a game in console using assembly language and I'll probably need to clear the screen at some time. And after that, to continue the game. Is there any way to do that in windows?

Comment: Try callig `clrscr`.  I think it's in msvcrt.dll but I'm not sure.

Comment: It didn't work but I think I've found another way to do that. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear!  It would be great if you could post an answer with the approach you found to help future people with the same issue.

Comment: I just print some empty lines until the console looks like it was cleared. It's not really a solution but it can be applied in my case so I'll use it. I think it's not possible to clear the screen using a function or something like that.